# Pi representation in a different number base

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, pi

Can pi be represented in a particular number base,so that it is no more an irrational number?

Comment: No. Pi is an irrational number, it doesnt care how you represent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The definition of rational number is independent of the base. The definition says that $x$ is irrational if and only if there doesn't exist a $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=p/q$. No mention of bases.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In any base the "decimal" expansion of a number eventually repeats if and only if the number is rational: a quotient $a/b$ of integers. The only part of this that depends on the base is whether or not the decimal terminates (that is, is $0$ from some point on).

The irrationality of $\pi$ means it can't be expressed as a quotient $a/b$ of integers.